# can i console log a file or data wihtout starting node server?

Tags: node.js

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

fs.readFile('test.html', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(data);
  })
  app.listen(3005,()=>{
    console.log("Server is Up on PORT 3005");
})
```

I want to console.log(data) without running nodejs server ? but how ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to perform operations in JS without starting up a server, this is traditionally known as a `script`. Scripts are usually run in an on-demand fashion rather than constantly running like a server. If you create a new script named `read-file.js`, you could run the script by running `node read-file.js` in your terminal.

To read a static file without a server, you could use the following script:

```js
const { readFile } = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');

readFile(join(__dirname, 'test.html'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: the question really confused me a lot before but now i see that instead of running the server ,i can just run the js file

Thanks for your effort it was really helpful

Comment: @SourabhSamyal Glad it helped! Feel free to mark the answer as the accepted answer so that the question can be closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could pass through an environment variable when running your node process. For example:

```
RUN=false npm run dev
```

Then within your code, process.env.RUN will be set based on what you passed in the command.

Simply surround the logic that starts the server based on the status of RUN:

```
if (process.env.RUN === "true") {
    // Start your server 
} else {
    // Do something
    fs.readFile('test.html', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(data);
      })
      app.listen(3005,()=>{
        console.log("Server is Up on PORT 3005");
    })
}
```

Comment: i could hardly think of this way , instead of writing a new read.js file i can do that too

shown me a new way of handling the work

really helpful , thank you for your effort